# MySQL Unknown column in where clause?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two databases. 
One is called `INFO` with three tables (`Stories`, `Comments`, `Replies`)

`Stories` has the following fields

```
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| storyID      | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| originalURL  | varchar(500)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| originalDate | timestamp      | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| numDiggs     | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| numComments  | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| diggURL      | varchar(500)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| rating       | varchar(50)    | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| title        | varchar(200)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| summary      | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| uploaderID   | varchar(50)    | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| imageURL     | varchar(500)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| category1    | varchar(50)    | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| category2    | varchar(50)    | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| uploadDate   | timestamp      | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| num          | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Another database is called `Data` with one table (`User`). Fields shown below:

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userID            | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| numStories        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numComments       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numReplies        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numStoryDiggs     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numCommentReplies | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numReplyDiggs     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numStoryComments  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numStoryReplies   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

`User.userID` is full of thousands of unique names. All other fields are currently `NULL`. The names in `User.userID` correspond to the names in `Stories.uploaderID`.

I need to, for each `userID` in `User`, count the number of stories uploaded from (i.e. num) `Stories` for the corresponding name and insert this value into `User.numStories`.

The query which I have come up with (which produces an error) is:

```
INSERT INTO DATA.User(numStories) 
SELECT count(num) 
FROM INFO.Stories 
WHERE INFO.Stories.uploaderID=DATA.User.userID;
```

The error I get when running this query is

```
 Unknown column 'DATA.User.userID' in 'where clause'
```

Sorry if this is badly explained. I will try and re-explain if need be.

Comment: Also, I have researched and I understand that similar questions have been asked on here before but none of these were able to help me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating new entries in the `User` table, you're updating existing ones. Hence, `insert` isn't the right syntax here, but rather `update`:

```
UPDATE DATA.User u
JOIN   (SELECT   uploaderID, SUM(num) AS sumNum
        FROM     INFO.Stories
        GROUP BY uploadedID) i ON i.uploaderID = u.userID
SET    numStories = sumNum
```

EDIT:
Some clarification, as requested in the comments.
The inner query sums the `num` in `Stories` per `uploaderId`. The `updates` statement updates the `numStories` in `User` the the calculated sum of the inner query of the **matching id**.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what your query does? I don't fully understand it. Thank you

Comment: @JacobHobbs I edited my answer to add some clarification. Let me know if this answers your question, or if it's still unclear, what needs to be clarified.